# jquery .insertAfter - Able to move element, but not move it back

Tags: jquery

On my template, I have a right sidebar container that when in a responsive(mobile) view needs to move to the top of the page. Because this container is lower in the DOM, it was showing below all my content. I wrote this script to move it, the problem is when you toggle between window sizes, it doesn't move back. (kinda am annoying bug for me that a user would never see)

a live example of the behavior can be found at http://sandbox.dev.activemls.com/agent/

here is my code:

```
var moveSidebar = function() {
    var windowsize = $(window).width(),
        isDesktop = windowsize > 765;
    if(!isDesktop) {
        $('#sidebar-3').insertAfter($('#sidebar-1'));
    }
    else if (isDesktop) {
        $('#sidebar-3').insertAfter($('#moveSidebar'));
    }    
}
$(document).ready(moveSidebar);
$(window).on("resize.showContent", moveSidebar);
moveSidebar();
```

and then the html looks like this:

```
<div id="sidebar-1">
     <!--sidebar content-->
</div>
<div id="sidebar-2">
     <!--sidebar content-->
</div>
<div id="moveSiderbar">
     <div id="sidebar-3" class="well well-small">
          <!--sidebar content-->
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have different ids:

```
<div id="moveSiderbar">

$('#sidebar-3').insertAfter($('#moveSidebar'));
```

Change one of them and it works

Comment: yes i know i have different ids. reason being, when the window size drops below 765px i need the id order to be sidebar-1, sidebar-3, sidebar-2. in it's default state, sidebar-3 needs to be within the moveSidebar container.

Comment: The problem is you don't have a `moveSidebar` container you have a `moveSiderbar` container. In order to return it to its default beginning state use `appendTo` instead of `insertAfter` http://jsfiddle.net/3Zvya/

Comment: @Binkley: but for the `insertAfter` method you need to give the id of an existing element (`moveSidebar` <-> `moveSiderbar`)

Comment: @Blake: thats' correct (if `sidebar-3` is supposed to end up back in `moveSidebar`), but that's not the main problem

Comment: Oh FFS...i have a typo in my IDs. Son of a biscuit maker!

Comment: Don't beat yourself up too hard. It happens to all off us sometimes ^^

Answer (score 1):

Change the id from 'moveSiderbar' to 'moveSidebar' or the other way around.